# Which is correct for the bushido code, 誠 or 真?

Tags: kanji, terminology, literature

Which one is correct for being used in the bushido code as *makoto*, 誠 or 真?

Answer (score 6):

You may or may not know that the so-called "Bushido code" was popularized (and somewhat canonized) by Inazo Nitobé [sic] in *Bushido: The Soul of Japan* (1900) and **first published in English**. One could say that the canon word for "veracity" in the sense of the "Bushido code" is the English word "veracity".

Only some years later, after being popular overseas, was the book translated into Japanese. This early translation (from 1908 by 桜井欧村) is [available at the 国立国会図書館 (*National Diet Library*)](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/758905/1). The translation uses the *kanji* **誠 *makoto*** for "veracity", which would also be the standard way of writing it now. Just be aware that "correct for the bushido code" is maybe not as clear as it would be if there were a canonical reference in Japanese.

Here is the relevant page from the Japanese translation of *Bushido: The Soul of Japan*.

[image: 武士道]

<sub>P.S. Note that there is some overlap with the Five Constants (五常) of Confucian ethics (仁 benevolence, 義・义 righteousness or justice, 禮・礼 proper rite, 智 knowledge, 信 integrity), where "veracity" or 誠 *makoto* may be matched to "integrity", written 信 which may also be read *makoto*.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you're asking.  Neither of those kanji are used to spell *bushidō*; both are used to spell *makoto*, in addition to (less commonly) the kanji 実.  In names, *Makoto* may also be spelled with single kanji as 允, 信, and 慎.

Comment: I think OP is referring to "bushido code" in the sense of the book *Bushido: The Soul of Japan*, where *makoto* is one of seven concepts that characterize *bushidō*.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: Thank you.  I also see that the question was reworded after I answered; the initial phrasing made it sound like a question about how to spell _bushidō_ in kanji.